# nodejs reachable from internet via react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, axios

I have a react app running on https and a nodejs running localhost:3001. my nodejs app does not capture data from react application.
What have I missed?

> server.js (Nodejs)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const Excel = require('exceljs');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors());


app.get('/', ()=>{
 console.log('welcome to test')
})
app.post('/api/xcl', (req, res) =>{

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile('test.xlsx')
.then(() =>{
const workSheet = workbook.getWorksheet('test');
workSheet.addRow([req.body.fNamn, req.body.eNamn, req.body.oNamn, req.body.ePost, 
req.body.dVal, req.body.kNamn]);
workbook.xlsx.writeFile('test.xlsx');
})
.catch(error => {
console.log(error.message);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(PORT, () => console.info(`server has started on ${PORT}`))
```

> app.js (Reactjs)

```
 axios.post('http://localhost/:3001/api/xcl', data)
        .then(res =>{
            setSent(true)
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(err=>console.log(err.response.data));
        })
```

I have declared the proxy   `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"` in package.json

React app runs on an iis site https://test.me:443

Comment: shouldn't it be ```http://localhost:3001/``` instead of ```http://localhost/:3001/``` ?

Comment: That's right, typo... But still not work!

Comment: can you try after removing the proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set proxy, you don't need to write http://localhost:3001 in your http request, try

```
axios.post('/api/xcl', data)
        .then(res =>{
            setSent(true)
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(err=>console.log(err.response.data));
        })
```

Comment: I tried in your way but without success, i get 404    Request URL: https://domainname.com/api/xcl
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: 192.181.211.201:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.
You can create your axios instance, and give it baseURL, then for
http calls use that instance of axios.

```
import axios from "axios";
const api = axios.create({
 baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
});

api.post('/api/xcl', data)
        .then(res =>{
            setSent(true)
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(err=>console.log(err.response.data));
        })
```

Comment: not working either, POST http://localhost:3001/api/xcl net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED... in somehow my frontend (React) does not recognize the backend (nodejs) to connect!!